# How can I count each row with duplicate entries in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to create a column `DisplayOrder` which will increment by 1 anytime there is a duplicate entry in `IdTitle_Code`

I've attempted to use `COUNT()` but the end result has been every row has a count of "1".

How can I increment the count by 1 anytime there are duplicate entries? Here is an example of my desired output:

| ReportId | ReportTitle | IdTitle_Code | DisplayOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | Test Report Title | 21 | 1 |
| 21 | Test Report Title 2 | 7 | 1 |
| 3 | Test Report Title 3 | 21 | 2 |
| 13 | Test Report Title 4 | 21 | 3 |
| 8 | Test Report Title 5 | 11 | 1 |

So in this example every time `"IdTitle_Code"` is 21 the `DisplayOrder` count goes +1. This would go for any duplicate entry, if there was another IdTitle_Code of 7 then the next entry would be +1.

Here is a code snippet:

```
CREATE TABLE TableOne
(
    ReportId INT,
    ReportTitle VARCHAR(100),
    IdTitle_Code INT,

)

INSERT INTO TableOne (ReportId,ReportTitle,IdTitle_Code)
VALUES (34,'Test Report Title',21),(21,'Test Report Title 2', 7), (3,'Test Report Title 3',21), (13,'Test Report Title 4',21) , (8,'Test Report Title 5',11) 



SELECT  ReportId, 
        ReportTitle, 
        IdTitle_Code,
        COUNT(IdTitle_Code) as DisplayOrder

FROM    TableOne
GROUP BY ReportId, ReportTitle, IdTitle_Code
```

This is my current result from the code snippet:

| ReportId | ReportTitle | IdTitle_Code | DisplayOrder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | Test Report Title | 21 | 1 |
| 21 | Test Report Title 2 | 7 | 1 |
| 3 | Test Report Title 3 | 21 | 1 |
| 13 | Test Report Title 4 | 21 | 1 |
| 8 | Test Report Title 5 | 11 | 1 |

All columns are returning 1. How can I get the DisplayOrder column to +1 anytime it's a new entry with the same `IdTitle_Code`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by idTitle_code order by reportTitle) as displayOrder
from tableone t;
```

Note that this requires one or more columns to define the ordering.  Based on your sample data, this uses `reportTitle`.